# cyrillic characters incorrect in html markup but visually correct

Tags: asp.net-mvc, character-encoding, url-encoding

I am developing a site in mvc4 where the content of the site includes both latin and cyrillic characters. Both are included in markup and both display correctly on screen.

However, within the markup, I have seen issues with cyrillic where url's for example are like following:

/%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%20%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9

The url navigate correctly when clicked on, but incorrect in html markup. I have the meta charset set to utf-8 in a meta tag.

Any ideas whats causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is correct [%-encoded](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) (aka. URL-encoded) form of the URL “/список пожеланий” (as you can see using a [decoder](http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/urlencode.php)). Browser may display a URL in their address bar as %-encoded, or as decoded to characters. HTML authoring software or, in manual editing of HTML code, the author should take care of %-encoding anything that needs to be %-encoded at the HTTP protocol level, such as `href` attribute values.

Comment: Ok - thanks. So what I have is correct. For SEO, can search engine bots see the correct url to index? ie. /список пожеланий

Comment: @amateur, search engines can be expected to know how to deal with %-encoded URLs, as %-encoding is standard and correct processing of URLs is crucial to search engines.